# +++ characters added to search string

Tags: php, jquery, search, post

I am using the following to autocomplete a search field.

```
 $(document).on('click','li.red-red', function(){
        var foo = $('input#search').val($(this).html());
    });
```

It works good, but when I press enter to run the search based off of the 
prepopulated text a bunch of ++++++ get added to the front and back of the search string.

```
++++++thing+to+search+here++++++++
```

It seems like that the autocomplete is leaving space before and after the term it puts into the text input.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: `$(this).html()` seems questionable...

Comment: I was also using $(this).text()

Answer (score 0):

try using `trim()` to remove any space that begins or ends the string

```
$(document).on('click','li.red-red', function(){
        var foo = $('input#search').val($(this).text().trim());
    });
```